# Why does my async js/nodejs function skip a big part?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

So I call the following function:

```
async function sql_func(){
    console.log('anothertest')
    async () => {
        console.log('third test')
        try {
            await sql.connect('heres the connection data')
            const result = await sql.query`heres a query`
            console.log(result) 
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

the first console log anothertest gets logged but the part inside the async () => {} just gets completly skipped. When debugging i see that it just jumps from the async() => { line straight to the closing bracket }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You defined a lambda function, but you're not actually calling it.

Comment: imagine if you will, that in your code you never called `sql_func()` ... the result would be the same, except even that one line that is executed would not be executed

Comment: @bravo and how do I call a () => function then? I dont know right now even so I used them before.

Comment: there's an answer below - but - why are you creating that IIFE?

Comment: @Bravo I dont know, little bit off today, doing a lot of unnecessary errors today. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
async function sql_func() {
    console.log('anothertest')
    await sql.connect('heres the connection data')
    const result = await sql.query`heres a query`
    console.log(result)
    return result
}
```

In your example there is no need to define another function: `async () => { }`. This function is never called. Also async functions handles all promises and rejects when a one of the promises is rejected. The catch you can do at the main function level:

```js
const result = await sql_func().catch(error => // do something)
// Or with try / catch
```

If you want a different error message (e.g.: hide the real error / stack trace):

```js
async function sql_func() {
    console.log('anothertest')

    await sql.connect('heres the connection data').catch(error =>
        Promise.reject('DB Connection error')
    )
 
    const result = await sql.query(`heres a query`).catch(error =>
        Promise.reject('Query failed')
    )

    console.log(result)
    return result
}
```